# KDE Plasma picture keeping clipboard manager

Tags: kde, manjaro, clipboard, plasma

As I know, Windows and Gnome clipboard manager can 'saves' pictures in clipboard manager. Is there a way to do something like that in Plasma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed :

- 1/ Right-Click on the clipboard manager icon
- 2/ Click on *Configure Clipboard* context menu option
- 3/ In the *General Configuration*, find the options for *Non-text selection*
- 4/ Choose the *Always save in history* option (as *Never* being the default)